# Unable to scroll the recyclerView to the top with smoothScrollToPosition(0)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm having a problem with scrolling the RecyclerView to the top when I tap the toolbar. What I want to do is to make it look like IOS. When I tap the toolbar I simply scrolls up to the top. I implemented the following code but doesn't work. the setSafeClickListener gets called but the smoothScrollToPosition is not doing anything. I would love to have some sample or hints from you!

```
private fun myRecyclerView(myListAdapter: MyRecyclerAdapter) {
        recyclerView = binding.myRecycleView
        recyclerView.isMotionEventSplittingEnabled = false
        // myLayoutManager extends the LinearLayoutManager
        recyclerView.layoutManager = myLayoutManager(context!!)
        recyclerView.adapter = couponListAdapter
        val appCompat = (activity as AppCompatActivity)
        val toolbar = appCompat.my_tool as androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        toolbar?.setSafeOnClickListener {
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you getting any warning log on click on toolbar?

Please check first is your toolbar onClick is working or not. Because you are accessing onClick on toolbar with null check may it is possible that toolbar is NULL!

Comment: tool bars click is working well no errors, I even added the break points

Comment: try adding a delay to your scroll to position code snipet .

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
```

and replace it in the onClick of the toolbar with

```
myLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
```

I hope it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into your activity

```
RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
  @Override protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
    return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
  }
};
```

Now you set the position where you want to scroll to:

```
smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
```

and pass that SmoothScroller to the LayoutManager:

```
myLayoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
```

Comment: You can apply my java code into kotlin as your requirement.